# Uncaught Error: [Topbar] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have looked at the previous questions and googled for the answer and I think I almost know what the issue in here is, but don't know how to solve it.

```
return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        {admin && (
          <>
            <Topbar />
            <div className="container">
              <Sidebar />
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
              <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />} />
              <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
              <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />} />
              <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />} />
              <Route path="/newproduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Please tell me how to setup the topar and slidebar components here.
Requesting my fellow coders to look at this one and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear, you only can use the `<Route />` tag, and remove the `<div className="container">` also.
Try this:

```
    return (
        <>
          <Topbar />
          <Sidebar />
          <Router>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              {admin && (
                  <>  
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
                    <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />} />
                    <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
                    <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />} />
                    <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />} />
                    <Route path="/newproduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
                  </>
              )}
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </>
)
```

Or you can import your TOPBAR and SIDEBAR components inside every other component.

Comment: Neither was a solution, but I moved, <Topbar /><Sidebar /> these inside the <Router> and then it was displayed

Answer (score 1):

to render a login page without a topbar and sidebar create a private router component and wrap it around all the routes you want to render a topbar and sidebar with
use [react-outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet)

here is what worked for me
app.js

```js
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import TopBar from "./Components/TopBar/TopBar";
import Home from "./Pages/Home/Home";
import UserList from "./Pages/UserList/UserList";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import User from "./Pages/User/User";
import NewUser from "./Pages/NewUser/NewUser";
import ProductList from "./Pages/ProductList/ProductList";
import Product from "./Pages/Product/Product";
import NewProduct from "./Pages/NewProduct/NewProduct";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Login from "./Pages/Login/Login";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const SidebarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <TopBar />
    <div className="container">
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </>
);

function App() {
  // const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin);
  const admin = JSON.parse(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user
  ).currentUser.isAdmin;
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<SidebarLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
          <Route exact path="/users/:id" element={<User />} />
          <Route exact path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
          <Route exact path="/products" element={<ProductList />} />
          <Route exact path="/products/:id" element={<Product />} />
          <Route exact path="/newProduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import UserList from "./UserList";
import NewUser from "./NewUser";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import Product from "./Product";
import NewProduct from "./NewProduct";
import Login from "./Login";
const AppRoute = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {admin ? (
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />} />
            <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />} />
            <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />} />
            <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />} />
            <Route path="/newproduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      ) : (
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default AppRoute;
```

Comment: Please share some comments about errors and changes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

````
  const admin = JSON.parse(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user
  ).currentUser.isAdmin;

  return (
    <Router>
      <>
        <Topbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Sidebar />
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/login"
              element={admin ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />}
            />

            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path="/users" element={<UserList />}></Route>
            <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User />}></Route>
            <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser />}></Route>
            <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />}></Route>
            <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product />}></Route>
            <Route path="/newproduct" element={<NewProduct />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </>
    </Router>
  ); ```
````

Comment: Try this , it worked  for me